# Make Outlook emails display as a separate icon on taskbar

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook-2010, taskbar

When I open/compose an email in Outlook, the window is kept in the Outlook stack, as following:

[image]

What I'd like to do is have the emails be stacked as a new icon, so clicking the Outlook icon will immediately maximize Outlook, rather than displaying the stack.
How can I do this?